# Does Qt support Windows Trackpad and Screen Rotate Gesture?

Tags: qt, touch

Windows appears to support gestures including pinch and two-finger rotate these days (maybe since W7?)

However from Qt documents Qt supports Pinch in seemingly two ways:

- `Qt::ZoomNativeGesture` from `QNativeGestureEvent`
- `QPinchGesture`

While rotate is only supported on `Qt::RotateNativeGesture` from `QNativeGestureEvent`

I'm not sure the difference between the two methods of pinch support, or if this means Qt only supports Mac rotate gestures... it doesn't really seem to be 100% clear what it *means* by "Native Gesture"?

And then, it's not clear if Qt supports on-screen gestures as opposed to trackpad gestures... are they separate things or does the OS treat a touch-screen as a trackpad anyway?